# Create new environment from terminal - hit error: git could not find the HEAD

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, environment

When I want to create environment for Elastic Beanstalk. (eb create new-dev-env)
I hit error as below:

ERROR: git could not find the HEAD; most likely because there are no commits present

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I get the answer.
Just need to commit the code in local repository.
Then it will create the git head.

After that, I can create the environment